# Simplifying static name

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
Corale.Colore.Core.Mousepad.Instance.SetStatic(Corale.Colore.Core.Color.Green);
```

However, how do I change this part...

```
Corale.Colore.Core.Color.Green
```

...to be more like so:

```
Color clr = Color.Green;
```

So that I may use it in this way:

```
Corale.Colore.Core.Mousepad.Instance.SetStatic(Corale.Colore.Core.clr);
```

Here is my use case:

```
DialogResult result = colorchoise.ShowDialog();

if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    color1 = colorchoise.Color;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Been a while... but...

```
using Color = Corale.Colore.Core.Color;
```

in your using statements should do it.

You could also add:

```
using Corale.Colore.Core;
```

which would reduce your statement to:

```
Mousepad.Instance.SetStatic(clr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `using` statements:

```
using clr = Corale.Colore.Core.Color.Green;
```

This will make you able to write like this:

```
Corale.Colore.Core.Mousepad.Instance.SetStatic(clr);
```

Comment: That does work, but how would i use this with a colorpicker?

Comment: DialogResult result = colorchoise.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                color1 = colorchoise.Color;
            }

Obv doesnt work,

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Color' to 'Corale.Colore.Core.Color'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Updated my answer to clarify. I don't really get what you want to do here. Can you post the exact code you are trying to use?

Comment: Use an explicit cast. Assuming color1 is the Corale.Colore variable you're trying to assign the value to, `color1 = (Corale.Colore.Core.Color) colorchoise.Color;`  (Edit:  made the wrong assumption originally. :))

Comment: Skerkles it was (Color)colorchoise.Color, but thanks it works amazing now  :D!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed thanks to skerkles:

```
color1 = (Color)colorchoise.Color;
```

And

```
using Color = Corale.Colore.Core.Color;
```